# TikZ - draw multiple bit strings/arrays

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-chains

I'm trying to draw multiple bit strings below and next to each other. Unfortunately, my current solution does not what I want. I've created a single bit string but adding another one next to it leads to the problem that it is cut off at the edge.

What I want is something like that: [example](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Crossover-and-mutation-operators-in-the-genetic-algorithm_fig3_2263212).
So I want another array on the right side and two others below.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=0pt,
 start chain = A going right,
    X/.style = {rectangle, draw,% styles of nodes in string (chain)
                minimum width=2ex, minimum height=3ex,
                outer sep=0pt, on chain},
                        ]
\foreach \i in {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0}
    \node(p1)[X] {\i};
\hspace*{5mm}
\foreach \j in {1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0}
    \node(p2)[X] {\j};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As for your meanwhile deleted comment: I added a possible way in the second part of my post below.

Comment: I changed your code to highlight a single element. Is there also a way to draw a thick border on specific elements, e.g. the 3th and the 6th of a single chain (and not on all chains)?

Comment: I think so. Probably you want to ask a separate question for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to start different chains.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=0pt,
    X/.style = {rectangle, draw,% styles of nodes in string (chain)
                minimum width=2ex, minimum height=3ex,
                outer sep=0pt, on chain},
                        ]
\begin{scope}[start chain = A1 going right]
\foreach \i in {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0}
    \node[X] {\i};
\end{scope}
% 
\begin{scope}[start chain = A2 going right,yshift=-1cm]
\foreach \j in {1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0}
    \node(p2)[X] {\j};
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[start chain = B1 going right,xshift=5cm]
\foreach \i in {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0}
    \node[X] {\i};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For a more structured construction of these you may work with `pic`s, and put them in a matrix. You can also add styles, here I added `ibold` which is an integer form which on the border will be drawn thick. You can add more of such keys as needed. `pic`s also have the advantage that the nodes inside inherit the name from the `pic`, so

```
 \draw[thick,-stealth] (L2-5.south) to[out=-90,in=90,looseness=0.6] (R3-4.north);
```

will connect the 5th node of the `L2` chain with the 4th node of the `R3` chain, as illustrated in

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ibold/.initial=20,
node distance=0pt,
    X/.style = {rectangle, draw,% styles of nodes in string (chain)
                minimum width=2ex, minimum height=3ex,
                outer sep=0pt, on chain},
                pics/.cd,chain/.style={code={
                    \begin{scope}[start chain =A going right,pic actions]
                \foreach \i [count=\j]in {#1}
                 {\unless\ifnum\j<\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ibold}
                 \tikzset{X/.append style={thick}}
                 \fi
                 \node  [X] (-\j) {\i};}
                \end{scope}
                }}]
\matrix[column sep=1cm,row sep=8mm]{
\pic[ibold=5](L1){chain={0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0}};
&
\pic[ibold=6](R1){chain={0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0}};\\
\pic[ibold=3](L2){chain={1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0}};
&
\pic(R2){chain={0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0}};\\
\pic(L3){chain={0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0}};
&
\pic(R3){chain={0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0}};\\
};
\draw[thick,-stealth] (L1-6.south) -- (R2-3.north);
\draw[thick,-stealth] (L2-5.south) to[out=-90,in=90,looseness=0.6] (R3-4.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]